# RaspberryPI/BCM2835 Memory Layout

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

I've been following the University of Cambridge's "BakePI" course but I have been finding some issue while determining the correct memory addresses of devices.

For instance: on their course they claim the System Timer is at location **0x20003000** but on the [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals datasheet](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) the timer is said to be available on location **0x7e003000**.

Same thing for all the other peripherals (GPIO controller, etc...).

Now, why the difference and how can I "translate" the address from the datasheet to a usable address?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

This is a result of the CPU dangling off the side of the GPU rather than being in charge of things - the ARM memory map isn't the same view of things as the GPU's bus layout.

From sections 1.2.3-1.2.4 of the datasheet:

> Physical addresses range from 0x20000000 to 0x20FFFFFF for
>   peripherals. The bus addresses for peripherals are set up to map onto
>   the peripheral bus address range starting at 0x7E000000. Thus a
>   peripheral advertised here at bus address 0x7Ennnnnn is available at
>   physical address 0x20nnnnnn.
>
> [...]
>
> **The peripheral addresses specified in this document are bus addresses.**

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet you pointed at shows you the address map for the gpu and the arm.  Yes it is a bit cryptic, well downright confusing...

The documentation is written from the perspective of the gpu where the base address in that processors address space for peripherals starts at 0x7E000000.  The arm and gpu share quite a bit, memory and peripheral access, but the peripherals are mapped into the ARM's address space starting at 0x20000000.

Basically wherever in that document you see 0x7Exxxxxx for some thing you want to program from the ARM replace that with 0x20xxxxxx.  It is that simple.

Comment: so if that is the case, then what would be 'physical address' one needs to use while mapping them in the current process virtual address space? IMHO it should be those of the ARM and not of the GPU, right? I mean Linux would be running on ARM after all right?

Comment: @HighOnMeat not sure I understand the question. Address spaces are not universal, they are relative to the local memory controller/address decoder.  The pi shares its dram with two processor/systems the gpu and the arm.  there is a place where those join.  The map in the documentation shows how that works.  They chose to have their primary map be gpu based or consider that the main system address space, and then you see how the arm taps into that.  software/operating systems on the arm would use the arms view of that world

Comment: this question is pretty old to allow for more ram space the latter chips changed from 0x20 to another address.  the arm maps into ram four ways each way with a different property, mips like.  so at least up to the pi3 the address space that maps into the peripheral/I/O space is nearer the top of that quarter something like 0x3F if I remember off hand which is as close as you can get for all practical purposes 2b00 for the top bits to indicate lower quarter then the next bits are ones to make it the top of that quarter.

Comment: the logic only allows for the arm to see the view that it sees, unless some of this is programmable and setup before the arm boots.  so linux or other arm software would need to conform to the address space from its view of the world.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, There is a big picture of BCM2835 ARM peripherals and Section 1.2 Address map explains well. ARM has its ARM virtual memory to manage their software whatever I don't know and we don't need to care of it. the most important thing is what is the bus address where we have to access the memory-mapped register in the kernel space using kernel-level device driver.

it says "mapped into a bus address by the ARM mapping MMU" and "the peripheral address specified in this document are bus addresses. software directly accessing peripherals must translate these address into physical or virtual addresses, as described above.."

this means the address you saw is the memory-mapped address (bus address) and the ARM core automatically translate it onto physical address.

the document is little bit confusing and you may refer to this source .dtd file(
[linux/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm283x.dtsi](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2710.dtsi)") on raspberry pi 3 which uses BCM2835 chip